# itemStateChanged and actionPerformed issues

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, listeners

I have a handler class which implements ActionListner, FocusListner, and ItemListner.  I have instantiated a gui object from a ConfrenceGUI class:

```
      public ConferenceGUI()
   {
      //Create a new JPanel and set its latyout mgr   
      conference = new JPanel(); 
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());  
      //create a RegPanel panel           
      regPanel = new RegPanel();
      //create new WorkshopPanel workshopPanel
      workshopPanel = new WorkshopPanel();      
      //build a buttonpanel
      buildButtonPanel();
      //Create a title panel      
      titlePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
      //create and set a font object
      titlePanel.setFont(new Font ("sansserif", Font.BOLD, 18));
      //add a label
      titlePanel.add(new Label("Select Registration Options"));      
      //Add the instantiated subpanels to the main conference gui panel
      add(titlePanel,        BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(regPanel,          BorderLayout.WEST);
      add(workshopPanel,     BorderLayout.EAST);
      add(buttonPanel,       BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      //add an item listener to the combo box
      ConferenceHandler handler = new ConferenceHandler(this);
      regPanel.regComboBox.addItemListener(handler);
      //add a focus listener to the name field
      ConferenceHandler fhandler = new ConferenceHandler(this);
      regPanel.regTextField.addFocusListener(fhandler);
   }
```

I am trying to take information from the listeners (including two button listeners from a separate method in my ConferenceGUI class, which I did not include).

Here is a snipped of code from my handler:

```
  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
  {
     String name = gui.regPanel.regTextField.getText(); 
     if (e.getSource() == gui.regPanel.regComboBox)
       {
          if (gui.regPanel.getRegType() == "Please select a type")
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select a registraion type",
                                        "Type Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);     
          else gui.textArea.setText(name+" is a " +
                                        gui.regPanel.getRegType()+ " registration");
       }
```

and for the buttons:

```
      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
  {
    String name = gui.regPanel.regTextField.getText();
    DecimalFormat $ = new DecimalFormat("$#,##0.00");
    if (e.getSource() == gui.calcButton)//if the calculate buttton is pressed
    {
       //dislplay error box if user selects index 0
       if (gui.regPanel.getRegType() == "Please select a type")
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select a registraion type",
                                                "Type Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
       //prints to textarea if registrant will be attending keynote or not
       if (gui.regPanel.regCheckBox.isSelected())
          gui.textArea.setText("Keynote address will be attended");
            else
              gui.textArea.setText("Keynote address will not be attended");
       //prints to textarea which workshops registrant will be attending
       gui.textArea.setText(name+" is registered in these workshops:" +
                            gui.workshopPanel.getWorkshopList());
       //prints total registration fees to textarea
       gui.textArea.setText("Total charges for" + name + " are " + $.format(calcTotalCharges()));
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == gui.clearButton)//if the clear button is pressed
    {
       //clear the textarea 
       gui.textArea.setText("");  
       //reset the list
       gui.workshopPanel.workshopList.setSelectedIndex(0);
       //reset the combobox to index 0
       gui.regPanel.regComboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
    }
  }
```

Problem will be obvious to all of you, but as I am just starting out, I can't figure out why I can't write any text into the textArea of my GUI.  Apologies for the amount of code, but I wanted to try to be thorough.

Here is where the textarea comes from (which is a sperarate method contained in my ConferenceGUI class:

```
   private void buildButtonPanel()
   {
      //create the buttonpanel
      buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
      //create the buttons
      calcButton = new JButton("Calculate Charges");
      clearButton = new JButton    ("Clear");
      //add listeners to the buttons
      ConferenceHandler ahandler = new ConferenceHandler(this);
      calcButton.addActionListener(ahandler);  
      clearButton.addActionListener(ahandler);
      //create a text area
      JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5,30); 
      textArea.setLineWrap(true); textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
      //add everything to the buttonpanel
      buttonPanel.add(calcButton); buttonPanel.add(clearButton); buttonPanel.add(new JScrollPane(textArea));
   }
```

There are three other classes RegPanel, and WorkshopPanel, both of which create a couple of panels for the ConferenceGUI, which is in turn instantiated by an applet (gui).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question (what doesn't work? What do you expect and what happens?), but what's sure is that calling `setText()` multiple times on a JTextArea is not a good idea : `setText` replaces the whole content of the text area. You should use `append()` to add multiple lines of text to the text area.

**EDITED :**

Now that you showed us how you built the text area, the problem is clearer : you instantiate a local variable textArea in the `buildButtonPanel` method, but the instance variable in your GUI points to another text area (or null).

**EDITED again :**

Your code is too complex and not complete enough to correct it, but the situation looks like this one :

```
public class Bug extends JPanel {
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(); // first text area

    private void build()  {
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(); // second text area. Inaccessible outside of this method
        this.add(new JScrollPane(textArea));
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.textArea.setText("foo"); // here, we modify the first text area, but it hasn't been added to the GUI, so it's invisible
    }
}
```

To fix it, you have to change it to this :

```
public class NoBug extends JPanel {
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(); // unique text area

    private void build()  {
        this.add(new JScrollPane(this.textArea));
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.textArea.setText("foo"); // here, we modify the unique text area, which has been added to the GUI in the build() method        }
}
```

Comment: okay, fair enough.  Appreciate that.  The purpose of my exercise is to collect information pertaining to a conference.  I am to supply an applet which allows the user to register attendees into different workshops, then calcualte the costs and return that (and a few other bits) into the textfield.

Comment: So what would be the proper coding to get to the textArea?  I wondered about that, but the only thing i could think of was gui.buttonPanel.textArea.setText() which didn't work....

Comment: If the listeners mofify the text area references by gui.buttonPanel.textArea, then the buildButtonPanel() method should initialize the variable gui.buttonPanel.textArea, and add this text area to the button panel. Does your code compile?

Comment: when I use the variable gui.buttonPanel.textArea, compiler returns a 'cannot find symbol - variable textArea

Comment: @JB Nizet - I have tried to restructure my code in the buildButtonPanel(), but when I put buttonPanel.add(new JScrollPane(this.textArea)), my whole buttonPanel no longer shows up on my applet.  So I screwed around with it, and changed everything to 'this' (as in 'this.add(calcButton);this.add(clearButton);this.add(new JScrollPane(this.textArea));  no luck.  Damn this is frustrating.  Oh, yeah, and thanks for the patience.  As an edit, I read the post from carmickr about making a getText(), should I be making getters and setters?  Nothing is mentioned in our assignment, it is usually very clear

Comment: I commented down below about how I fixed it (as usual, silly new guy mistake).  But I just wanted to thank you for taking some time to help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

> Apologies for the amount of code, but I wanted to try to be thorough

Actually the code you posted doesn't help much because we don't know the context of how the code is used.

Your code references a "gui" object, but we don't know when/how this variable is created. You reference a "textArea" object as well and same comment. So the code you posted is incomplete.

If you can't add text to a text area then one of two things is happening:

a) the code is not ever being executed (you can add System.out.println(...) to verify this).
b) you have the wrong reference to the textArea compnent that has been added to the GUI. There could be many reasons for this. Maybe you have both a class and local variable of the same name.

If you need more help post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: the gui object is instantiated from the top method ConfrenceGUI.  The text area in question comes from a buildButtonPanel method which I will post up top.

Comment: @unit, Did you read my comment about class/local variables? You infact have a local text area. There is no way we could tell this from your original question that is why you need to post a SSCCE we don't waste time guessing what your code looks like. Get rid of the local varialble and then create a getTextArea() method that you can use to reference the class variable. You should never write code to access variables in a class directly.

Comment: My apologies for wasting your time.  It must be very frustrating trying to help people who are new.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Mr.  camickr, thank you.  I went through my pgm, and realized that I had declared the text area twice, once up top, and once in the method.  All I had to do was remove the TextArea part in the method so it then read 'textArea = new JTextArea", and now it's working!  Thanks

Comment: @unit, my comment was about giving you a suggestion about something to look at and yet all you did was pasted the code without actually looking at it for the local variable. Since I initially made the suggestion about the problem being a class/local variable problem, why wasn't my answer accepted? I also suggeste "the proper" way to solve this is to create a method. Again the suggestion has apparently been ignored.